# Why doesn't the audio work after refreshing the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wavesurfer.js

There is an audio file that needs to be played from the visualization on wavesurfer.js did. did play , stop everything works but I need to make it so that the audio itself starts. it did as document.querySelector(".play").click(); . when you go to the page using a link from another page the site all works fine and when you refresh it does not work.
Can you help solve this problem . thanks.
`your text`
I thought it was the cache or something else.

```
class AudioMessage {
    constructor(container, audioLink) {
      this.audioLink = audioLink;
      this.speed = 1;

      this.elements = {};
      this.elements.container = container;
      this.elements.playToggle = container.querySelector('[data-play-toggle]');
      this.elements.wave = container.querySelector('[data-wave]');
      this.elements.time = container.querySelector('[data-time]');
      this.elements.speedToggle = container.querySelector('[data-speed-toggle]');

      this.wavesurfer = WaveSurfer.create({
        container: this.elements.wave,
        waveColor: '#E0E0E0',
        progressColor: '#00D45D',
        barWidth: 2,
        barHeight: 3, // the height of the wave
        barGap: 2,
        height: 40,
        cursorWidth: 0,
      });
      this.wavesurfer.load(this.audioLink);
      this.wavesurfer.on('ready', () => {
        this.setTime(this.wavesurfer.getDuration());
        this.elements.playToggle.addEventListener('click', this.togglePlay.bind(this));
        this.elements.speedToggle.addEventListener('click', this.toggleSpeed.bind(this));

        this.wavesurfer.on('audioprocess', () => {
          this.setTime(this.wavesurfer.getCurrentTime());
        });
        
        this.wavesurfer.on('seek', () => {
          this.play();
        });
      });
    }
    togglePlay(state) {
          this.elements.container.classList.toggle('AudioMessage--active');
          this.wavesurfer.playPause();
          
    }

    play() {
      this.elements.container.classList.add('AudioMessage--active');
      this.wavesurfer.play();


    }

    toggleSpeed() {
      this.speed += 0.5;
      if (this.speed > 2) {
        this.speed = 0.5;
      }
      this.wavesurfer.setPlaybackRate(this.speed);
      this.updateSpeed();
    }

    setTime(seconds) {
      const intSeconds = Math.trunc(seconds);
      const padMinutes = String(div(intSeconds, 60)).padStart(2, '0');
      const padSeconds = String(mod(intSeconds, 60)).padStart(2, '0');

      this.elements.time.textContent = `${padMinutes}:${padSeconds}`;
    }

    updateSpeed() {
      this.elements.speedToggle.textContent = `${this.speed}x`;
    }
  }
 
  const messages = [];

  document.querySelectorAll('[data-audio-message]').forEach((message) => {
    let mess = new AudioMessage(message, audioGolos)
    messages.push(mess);
    
  });
```